# Склонение фамилий Борджиа и Сфорца

Tags: ономастика, склонение-фамилий

Склоняются ли иностранные фамилии **Борджиа** и **Сфорца** (как для мужчины, так и для женщины)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Эти фамилии не склоняются, что можно видеть из различных текстов, где они упоминаются.

Например: Наиболее видным представителем династии был Людовико Моро, сначала правивший неофициально при своем малолетнем и слабовольном племяннике герцоге Джан Галеаццо **Сфорца**...

Тему склонений различных фамилий рассматривает Розенталь [http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/57.htm#з_06](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/57.htm#%D0%B7_06)

1) **Борджиа**

Иностранные фамилии **на -иа не склоняются,** например: сонеты Эредиа, рассказы Гулиа; на -ия – склоняются, например: зверства Берии.

2) **СфОрца**

Иностранные фамилии, оканчивающиеся **на гласный звук** (кроме неударяемых -а, -я, с предшествующим согласным) **не склоняются**, например: романы Золя, стихотворения Гюго, оперы Бизе, музыка Пунчини, пьесы Шоу, стихи Салмана Рушди.

В данном случае гласный А безударный, **но из текстовых примеров мы видим, что фамилия не склоняется** http://search1.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%D1%F4%EE%F0%F6%E0

Почему? Попробуем сравнить с фамилией ***Капица***  (эта фамилия склоняется): Ещё до защиты диплома А. Ф. Иоффе приглашает ***Петра Капицу*** на работу в Физико-технический отдел... По одной из версий "капица" (рум.) — стог сена, (учитывая,что П. Капица родом из Бессарабии).

Получается, что в правиле указано **необходимое, но не достаточное условие** для склонения фамилии. У ***Сфорца*** явно не русская фонетика, в отличие от ***Капицы***,  и падежные формы (Сфорцы, Сфорце, Сфорцей) могут восприниматься как начальная форма фамилии, а это нужно исключить.

О склонении **мужских и женских фамилий**

Вообще говоря, **склоняемость иностранных фамилий зависит от того, насколько они вписываются в словоизменительную систему** в русском языке, например:

Русские и иноязычные фамилии, оканчивающиеся на согласный звук, склоняются, если относятся **к мужчинам (это 2-е склонение. м. р.),** и не склоняются, если относятся **к женщинам** (нет такого склонения для сущ. ж.р. на твердый согласный). Ср.:  у Джорджа Буша – у Барбары Буш.

Comment: Сфорца как раз относится к фамилиям с неударяемой -а, с предшествующим согласным. Это итальянские аристократы, а не французские.

Comment: Сфорца» (от итал. sforzare — «напрягать, давить». Я сначала послушала, как произносится итальянский глагол sforzare, там ударение не на первом слоге, но в sforza действительно  на первом слоге.

Comment: В итальянском вообще на последнем слоге ударение практически не встречается (общая тенденция - к предпоследнему).

Answer (score 2):

> Нерусские фамилии на *неударяемые* -о, -а (в основном славянские и
>   романские) склоняются (*Джульетты Мазины*); ... фамилии на -иа не склоняются
>   (*рассказы Гулиа*).
>   http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/57.htm#%D0%B7_06

Здесь обе фамилии итальянские, ударение на первом слоге. Соответственно, 
**Сфо́рца** склоняется, **Бо́рджиа** - нет.

**P.S.** Для фамилии **Сфорца** в литературе наблюдаются существенные колебания в склонении - несклонении.

Comment: В Нацкорпусе 121 пример с несклоняемой фамилией Сфорца http://search1.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%D1%F4%EE%F0%F6%E0  У Вас есть примеры, где фамилия склоняется?

Comment: Страница из книжки: https://books.google.ru/books/content?id=zEBjBgAAQBAJ&pg=PT257&img=1&zoom=3&hl=en&ots=BCqzGgBbdZ&sig=ACfU3U1hKu1LwJBI2rS1lzxQXMOcVlRD2Q&w=1280 Но колебания - да, наблюдаются.

Comment: Колебания - это мягко сказано, я думаю, что речь идет о единичных случаях. СквОрцы - это почти наши скворцЫ, Скворцей - не лучше.  Такое искажение фамилии недопустимо. Нельзя ориентироваться на формальное частное решение, когда есть общее правило: обеспечить минимальное искажение имени собственного.

Comment: Брокгауз с Ефроном и Мережковский (даже скудным "корпусом" у него находится "Сфорцы") не брезговали склонением. Можно в книжках любое количество найти, даже с "Ланцей" встречается. А где рекомендация для Ц изложена?

Comment: Любопытно, что Кустурицу обычно склоняют (на птицу похоже). А что, есть фамилия Скворца?

Comment: Ну опять же единичные примеры,  они погоды не делают. И не всё же на авторитеты оглядываться и пример с них брать, они тоже люди и могут ошибаться.  Например, Аристотель считал, что тяжёлые тела падают быстрее, чем лёгкие,  и все ему 1500 лет верили. Почему не надо склонять Сфорца? Потому что Сфорцы, Сфорцей может восприниматься как фамилия в начальной форме. А если про Ц Вам интересно, то это моё личное мнение (видите, в ответе есть слово "ВОЗМОЖНО"). А если у Вас есть своё мнение, то скажите, пожалуйста, нужно ли склонять фамилию Скворца? Какие для этого есть за и против?

Comment: Но желательно в ответе, а не в комментариях.

Comment: Можно привести любое нужное для "неединичности" количество примеров из книг. С гипотетической же фамилией СквОрца (как и с фамилиями без Ц, напр. Петарда вместо Петрарки) можно поступать по-разному. Если есть опасения, что неверно восстановят окончание, можно в начале текста ввести её в именительном падеже, затем (где есть опасность спутать с деревней Скворцы) можно поставить ударение и т. д.

Comment: Отказ от склонения не спасает от неудобств. Например, чтобы поставить в творительный падеж традиционно не склонявшегося Марио Ланца (даже без склонения неясно: а вдруг это Ланц?), приходится повторять видовое наименование этой знаменитости.

Comment: P.S. В книжках пишут не Сфорцей, а Сфорц**о**й (для мужских и женских фамилий).

Comment: Тогда да, если уж в книжках так пишут, то  давайте будем склонять этого Сфорцу.